# Windows 7 program files folder

Tags: subdirectory

I have an application contained in a folder that uses temporal files stored in its own folder.
If I copy it directly to "Program Files" folder it fails to find the route to its own subfolders but if I copy it to any other folder and perform any action there (such as create a file in my app's folder) and then move it to "Program Files", everything works perfectly fine.

¿Any idea on the reason why can this be?

Comment: Can you provide us the details of the exception you get?

Answer (score 0):

Any chance that this has something to do with the space between Program and Files? I find it hard to believe that it only doesn't work with the specific folder.